# Correlation between vectors with non-matching y values without using interpolation

Tags: time-series, correlation, interpolation, down-sample

Is there a way to calculate the correlation between two time series that have been adaptively downsampled and thus (may) have different y values? This is easiest to explain with an example, so consider the case of two downsampled time series (n=100->down_n=5) in the range of time-points 1 to 100:

```
S1 = (10,1), (20,30.5), (30,35), (40,70.95), (50,100)

S2 = (10,1), (15,10), (40,80.2), (45,85), (60, 100)
```

Because the x values are all increasing, there is a definite correlation, however the oddly spaced y values mean that it's not as strong as it initially seems.

I know I could interpolate so the y values match (or just add some of the original points back in), but I have downsampled because of memory constraints in other processing so I want to avoid adding points back in.

Hopefully this makes sense. I tried to keep it clear without overloading information. Thanks in advance!

EDIT - To clarify the data:
In the example x is the value and y is the time. In the downsampling, floating point y values can be interpolated. So (10,1) means that at time point 1, the observed value was 10, while (20,30.5) means at time point 30.5, it is likely/interpolated that the value for x would have been 20.

Comment: Couldn't you downsample matching sets?

Comment: All the data is initially of n=100 with matching y values, but it's downsampled so areas of high variance are represented by more points. So in the example above, there's not much variation in the original S2 between y=10 and y=80 which is why I haven't taken any samples between them.

Comment: Slightly confused by the notation. Does x represent time, and y is some variable that depends on it? Does (10,1) mean that x=10, y=1?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have clarified. In the example x is the value and y is the time. In the downsampling, floating point y values can be interpolated. So (10,1) means that at time point 1, the observed value was 10, this (20,30.5) means at time point 30.5, it is likely/interpolated that the value for x would have been 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) (DTW) to do this:

> DTW is an algorithm for measuring similarity between two temporal sequences which may vary in speed.

The advantage of DTW is that it neither needs to have a steady rise/declination in the time series (as in your example), nor needs the variance in speed be steady over time: DTW can deal with both using its warping. *Therefore the timestamps of samples don't play any role any more, just the ordering of samples in the series matters.* The downside of DTW is that it has $n^2$ complexity, so you will probably need to downsample very long series first, or use a complexity limitation like the Sakoe Chiba band (see e.g. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtw/dtw.pdf) or [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.0041.pdf)).

Here's a short DTW example in R using the `dtw` package:

```
> library(dtw)
> plot(beaver1[,3], type='l', ylim=c(36,39))
> lines(beaver2[,3], col=2)
> d1 <- dtw(x = beaver1[,3], y = beaver2[,3])
> d1$distance
[1] 54.9
> plot(d1) # shows the warping path
```

[image: DTW 1]

... adding a Sakoe Chiba window to restrict complexity:

```
> d2 <- dtw(x = beaver1[,3], y = beaver2[,3], window.type = 'sakoechiba', window.size = 15)
> d2$distance
[1] 97.97
> plot(d2) # shows the warping path
```

[image: DTW 2]

Comment: That looks perfect! Thank you for the information and examples. The complexity shouldn't be too much of an issue for me as it's not a time critical process and my series are already heavily downsampled, but I'll have a look at the Sakoe Chiba band too.

p.s. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to vote for your answer. I would if I could!

Comment: Glad I could help ;)